# C# Asynchronous Tcp Server with SSL. How can I get mutual authentication with iOS NSStream?

Tags: c#, ios, cross-platform, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

This is my first post at stackoverflow.com, so if i do something wrong just let me know. So onto the problem.

I have a `C#` server currently running `System.Net.Socket` Sockets similar to the sample code Microsoft provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx).

I also have an `Objective-C` iPad client running `NSInputStream/NSOutputStream` bound to `CFReadStream/CFWriteStream`.

At present with only username/password authentication sent via an `XML Serialized Object` the client and server can communicate without any issues.

The problem I now have is that the communication has to be secure, and talking to clients, `SSL encryption` would be acceptable. However, I don't think they would accept just the "Server Certificate" as good enough. So I am trying to get the iPad client to use a "Client Certificate". I would like to enable true mutual authentication.

If I can't achieve mutual authentication, a third party `VPN` Software could be the better solution to secure the communication.

I haven't completed the conversion yet, but I have found a few articles that give me good examples of this, but there are no examples that fit my situation for client side certificates on the iPad.
The samples that i have found are:

[C# SSL Tcp Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2007/06/13/sample-asynchronous-sslstream-client-server-implementation.aspx)

[Apple Developer site that shows how to use SSL, but no client certificate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html)

[iPad SSL Stream without client certificate.](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/nsstream-tcp-and-ssl.html)

[iPad SSL Stream without client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700819/problem-with-nsstream-ssl-connection)

[iPad HTTP Client that uses client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513291/ios-mutual-authentication-solved)

Basically the system must eventually run `TCP` communication with `SSL` embedded with the ability to manage certificates. Not sure if it makes a difference, but as this would be going to many different clients, it is preferable to be compatible with `SSL 3.0` and `TLS`(any version).

As I have only been dabbling in `Objective-C` for the past 6 months and am more familiar with `C#`, I will probably need you to explain your answer in simpler terms.

**Edit:**
I am more concerned with the `Objective-C` side of the equation, as I am fairly sure the `C#` side will be simple. Basically I need someone to explain how to implement client side certificates on a `TCP NSStream` in `Objective-C` or point me in the direction of possible solutions or approaches to the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Possibly you can find your answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795344/nsstream-handle-event-giving-status-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer your question with regards to how to implement this on the objective-c side as what you ask is beyond what a single application can achieve *on IOS devices*. Thinking outside the box..

From Apple:

> iOS supports the Simple Certificate Enrollment Protocol (SCEP). SCEP
>   is an Internet draft in the IETF, and is designed to provide a
>   simplified way of handling certificate distribution for large-scale
>   deployments. This enables over-the-air enrollment of identity
>   certificates to iPhone and iPad that can be used for authentication to
>   corporate services.

Knowing this and searching for SCEP in the developer library points me to this page - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html

This page will be of interest, notice that Microsoft Server supports this:-
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH3-SW1 and it even has some sample client/server code.

My interest is generally in the field of Mobile-Device-Management and have been looking into this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To be honest i had given up on a response to this post as my question is a bit out there. I will have to reconsider my communication channel to use certificates. I think this is the best answer, but i have to give upvotes to both answers. (on a side note, i found that rsa has an API in a few different languages, which if your clients have rsa keys may be a better option).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CFSocket](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html) and/or [CkoSocket](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/objcCkoSocketRef.html)